# difference between progress ON and progress OF

Tags: prepositions

I'm still confused even after studying the prepositions on and of. Can you please help me and explain to me the difference of the ff:

> 1. progress ON your project
> 2. progress OF your project

When should I use on? of?

Answer (score 6):

This depends upon the wider context in which the sentence is used.  The two examples you have given do not, on their own, make sense.

If the progress is the subject then *of*, if you are the subject then *on*.

*Have you made any progress on your project?*

*What is the progress of your project?*

*I have made progress on my project*

*There has been progress on the project*

*The progress of the project is satisfactory*